# Ignore query params in service worker requests

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I am trying to build an offline app using service workers. I have a list of resources defined like

`var urlsToPrefetch = ['foo.html', 'bar.js']`

Query strings are added to many of the urls and that is causing the service worker's `fetch` event to fail since the request doesn't match what is defined in the cache. The query strings are mainly used to force fetching of new file versions. For instance, `bar.js` is requested as `bar.js?version=2`

There is an option for ignoring query strings (`ignoreSearch` below), although this is not yet implemented as of Chrome V50. Chrome Canary is only available for Win/Mac

The below code is in the `fetch eventListener`

```
event.respondWith(
    // caches.match() will look for a cache entry in all of the caches available to the service worker.
    // It's an alternative to first opening a specific named cache and then matching on that.

    caches.match(event.request, {'ignoreSearch': true} ).then(function(response) {
        if (response) {

            return response;
        }

        ...
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new request removing the query string and then use it instead of the original one:

```
var url = new URL(request.url);
url.search = '';
url.fragment = '';

let cleanRequest = new Request(url, {
  method: request.method,
  headers: request.headers,
  mode: request.mode,
  credentials: request.credentials,
  cache: request.cache,
  redirect: request.redirect,
  referrer: request.referrer,
  integrity: request.integrity,
});
```

Comment: The `Request` will be created automatically if you just pass in a URL string. See 5.4.2.3.3 of https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/index.html#cache-matchall-method It's also not necessary to copy over all the other `Request` properties, since only the URL matters to the Cache Storage API.

Comment: Yes, and it is actually better if you only need to use the cache, because the `Request` constructor could throw if `referrer` is a cross-origin URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
function stripQueryStringAndHashFromPath(url) {
  return url.split("?")[0].split("#")[0];
}

function onFetch(event) {
  const requestUrl = stripQueryStringAndHashFromPath(event.request.url.replace(/^.*\/\/[^\/]+/, ''));
... all the other jazz
}
```

This will give you just the path name. For example `/?test=1#three` will give you just `/`.

Answer (score -1):

use `Request` instead:

```
var requestsToCache = [
  new Request('foo.html'),
  new Request('bar.js')
];
// ...
  cache.addAll(requestsToCache);
// ...
```

Comment: This only works if you want to cache everything on install.